# Como alterar o valor de um argumento inteiro passado como referência em Julia?

Tags: funções, parâmetros, referência, julia

```
function muda_o_valor_do_inteiro!(x::Int64)
    x = 10
end

a = 9

muda_o_valor_do_inteiro!(a)
println(a) # a deveria possuir o valor 10
```

Eu já entendi que com vetores eu consigo modificar o valor de dentro dele, entretanto como eu faço isso para variáveis inteiras, reais, booleanas, entre outras?

Comment: E por que não faz do jeito certo e aí não precisa disto?

Comment: Quer algo como [`unsafe_store`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#Base.unsafe_store!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sou especialista em Julia mas pelo que eu pesquisei não tem como fazer isto e não deveria fazê-lo, inclusive este código não faz sentido, se quer gerar um resultado dê um `return` e se quer mudar o valor da variável que foi usada na chamada da função então faça uma atribuição nela com o resultado da função.

Se ainda for tão importante assim passar algo por referência, o que eu duvido, então use um *container* com o valor que pode ser alterado, pode encapsular o valor em um *array* e assim a mudança lá dentro da função se refletirá fora, mas ainda terá que criar esse *array*, depois pegar o valor dentro dele. Mas novamente, não faz sentido na maioria dos cenários, principalmente um artificial assim. Até onde eu sei não tem como mudar o comportamento de um argumento diretamente por valor.

Comment: Tava vendo aqui, é _possível_ pegar o ponteiro de uma variável usando `myvar[]`. Não vi como faz para setar esse valor. Também questiono a utilidade disso, visto que Julia permite retornar tuplas facilmente

Comment: Que foi o que eu falei.